# is it possible for wordpress theme to work without wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, themes

I have bought this Wordpress theme:
http://themeforest.net/item/wp-pro-real-estate-3-responsive-wordpress-theme/1763306?ref=contempoinc
but I was stupid enough to forget that Wordpress will need to be installed in order to customize and work on it. Is it possible to run it on some server without Wordpress being include, to consider it as "done" template?

Comment: ...why don't you just install Wordpress? It's really easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not in any practical way. Themes operate inside WordPress the way FireFox addons work inside Firefox or the way an Android App needs Android (to a lesser extent).

You must have WordPress to use a WordPress theme. There are too many class and function dependencies to run the theme without WordPress. It would be near impossible to even a load a theme and get all the templates to work without the WordPress core managing things.

You are better off starting from scratch than you are trying to edit the "WordPress" out of a WordPress theme.